# How would I go about displaying a table from SQL with PHP A-Z where after 10 rows the script starts a new table next to it

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to display SQL table data with PHP, right now I have made an HTML table that infinitely loops up until the end of the page. Now I want to try and display 10~ names vertically before starting a new HTML table next to it that continues looping until the entire SQL table is displayed. The script I have right now is as follows.

```php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, id FROM table ORDER BY name");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
    echo "<table>
    <tr><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"select\" value=\"" . $row['name'] . "\"></input></td></tr>
    </table>" ;    
}
```

Comment: You create a variable `$counter` and update it inside the while loop. When you counted a multiple of 10 rows you close the table and open up a new one and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want to have a table for each 10 rows , if thats the case you can do it as follows :

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, id FROM table ORDER BY name");
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        print "<table>";
    } elseif ($i == 10) {
        print " </table><table>";
        $i = 1;
    }
    echo "
    <tr><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"select\" value=\"" . $row['name'] . "\"></input></td></tr>
    ";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, now I am wondering why $row['name'] returns "name 1 & name 2 . .. " whilst when I tried to print $row['name'] twice before and it only returned "name 1 & name 1"

Comment: in the code you referred printing the row[name] happens each time mysql_fetch_array returns an array of result and $row variable gets created . maybe before the code was different or some other problems ...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fetch all the rows into a table and then split it into chunks of 10.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, id FROM table ORDER BY name");
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach (array_chunk($data, 10) as $table) {
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        echo "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"select\" value=\"" . $row['name'] . "\"></input></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```